# Regarding Showreels/Demo's/Etc on SSD

Tags: showreel, design

Although I think it's very smart to ask for comments on showreels and other sound design projects, I don't think this is what SSD is meant for. I get the feeling people are using it as a means of getting attention for their work, instead of accelerating debate on sound design topics. We can of course learn from each others work. However I think talking about end products is much less interesting than discussing design issues.

How do other participants/contributors of SSD think about this?

UPDATE:

I've been thinking about my question and the responses it has received. Although I agree with most of you I still feel the same about my concern. But I guess I wasn't very clear as to why it is a concern to me and could be to others.

I believe that this forum is very interesting because we can talk about issues in the design process. This is valuable information comparable to talking with colleagues on the work floor. But most of us don't have colleagues around, work on their own, with a deadline ahead. In other words there is no easy way to get an answer quickly to common issues. And exactly this is what SSD is very good at.

Providing feedback to an online demo reel is still a good way to talk about sound. But those demo reels tend to disappear after a year or so. This doesn't mean it's not useful to post demo reels etc. But as an online resource SSD has the ability to become a go-to source with instant advice for an emerging work field with newcomers on a daily basis. They are welcome to share demo reels, but I'm personally more interested in a their thoughts and those of other more experienced designers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's necessarily out of form. If someone is posting here in hopes of gaining attention or exposure within the sound community, they're wasting their time. If, however, they're looking for honest and constructive criticism, they've got a good chance of finding it.

To be honest, I tend to ignore reel posts. I just don't have the time to sit down, view/audition and formulate a critique. I do know that there are other people who have the time to respond and do. Even if it's just students/young professionals talking amongst themselves, discussion is an important element in professional growth. Not everyone comes here seeking to expand the discussion within the sound industry. Many come simply to learn. Let them have the opportunity to discuss the lower level topics, and one day they'll be contributing to the higher level ones.

Comment: Hi Shaun, I agree that it's good practice to discuss demo's and each others work. I respond to demo reels because I think that is important. But I saw a rise in questions about demo reels and simply wanted to adress this. Furthermore, it's a forum/community for questions and I hoped to fire up a discussion about what could be a better way to ask questions about a demoreel (by the maker itself). Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 4):

I think peer critiques are great, especially for folks just starting out in sound design.  There's a neat little subreddit called r/RateMyAudio that is meant just for this and it could definitely use a larger active community.

Comment: Hi, never knew about that subreddit, interesting! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[alt text http://s7.postimage.org/3o45ulnuz/Screen_shot_2013_02_19_at_15_44_40.png](http://s7.postimage.org/3o45ulnuz/Screen_shot_2013_02_19_at_15_44_40.png)

Comment: Ofcourse feedback can be given, and I do so myself. It was more a matter of adressing the rise in demo reel posts over time.

Answer (score 1):

Although I do agree with most of what Shaun has said, there could/can be a quantity issue here.  If every other post is asking for critique or beginner questions it would become very tiresome very quickly.  Do we really want to descend into the constant "how do I make this sound" posts on some other forums?  I personally have lost interest in other places for this very reason.   In addition, I am mindfull that there are learning environments available to students where they can and do get feedback from their tutors.

Comment: good points, but it hasn't been a big issue here thus far. the community here has also been very diligent about self-policing (this thread might be an example). hopefully we can continue that.

Comment: Agreed.  IMO this is largely down to the efforts of the regular posters.  Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

Well as being someone who just posted my sound design project, I agree it can feel a bit like a self promotion. However, I believe that if the sound design project in mind can bring up interesting and helpful discussion to more members than the person who posted it, then it definitely fit's into Social Sound Design!

I see how this site could turn into hundreds of post looking for critique, but I guess that's what tags are for? Maybe they should make subforums like GS :P

Good question Arnoud!

Comment: Thanks! A subforum would be something to discuss with andrew spitz, and in my opinion a bit too much of a prescription for newcomers. I do however hope that posting demo reels is not going to become the general purpose of an otherwise interesting and viable source of information and discussion. 